# ajax:success callback doesn't work in rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a small form on the page that looks like

```
<div id="updater">
    <%= form_for current_user,:remote=>true do |f| %>
        please update your <%= f.label @field %>: 
        <%= f.text_field @field %>
        <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
 </div>
```

This triggers the Users#update which has `respond_to format.js`

update.js.erb is

```
$("#updater").bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
    $("#updater").remove();
});
```

so the form will disappear once the the field has been updated

I see that the JS is sent on the network tab on the chrome inspect thingy and the field does update in the DB. yet the #updater doesn't disappear, not if I add `alert("updater");` I don't see the alert.

Am I not catching the ajax:success correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have another js file that is working on #updater.. once I removed that it started working..